# TinyLogs issues while using in Kotlin Android Project

Tags: martini

I am seeing the logs in my console/logcat but I do not see the logs in my file. Someone help me with. I have to use it for my Log Rotation implementation in my Android **Kotlin** Project

I tried creating tinylog.properties in resources folder as suggested over many places, and I also tried setting the path of the logging file programatically in my onCreate() method. Someone help me with it.

Comment: Update - After adding media permission for my Android 14, I can see the logs in my file too.
Now I want am trying to use rolling file as the write for my tinyLogs but not seeing the desired reults, like I am seeing only the last log in my myFileLog.txt and the previous logs are not visible to my in my archive folder